# Differentiate between similar records

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have some input XML that is auto generated(so I am unable to rename the fields accordingly):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csv-xml>
   <record>
      <csv-field-1>1</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>7654321</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>1</csv-field-4>
      <csv-field-5>08/08/19</csv-field-5>
      <csv-field-6>08/08/19</csv-field-6>
   </record>
   <record>
      <csv-field-1>2</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>12345678</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>3</csv-field-4>
   </record>
   <record>
      <csv-field-1>2</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>22345679</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>7</csv-field-4>
   </record>
   <record>
      <csv-field-1>2</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>32345680</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>6</csv-field-4>
   </record>
   <record>
      <csv-field-1>2</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>42345681</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>2</csv-field-4>
   </record>
   <record>
      <csv-field-1>3</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3></csv-field-3>
   </record>
</csv-xml>
```

I am trying to figure out how to use an XSLT transformation to take out the data I need when records have the same path/name.

I have tried using:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/csv-xml/record/csv-field-2/node()"/>
```

But the output is:

```
1234512345123451234512345
```

Code Used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"   
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="text"
            media-type="text/plain"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/csv-xml/record/csv-field-2/node()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My expected result would be from the first 'csv-field-2' something like:

```
<name>12345</name>
```

My final goal is to be able to extract all the data needed from these XML's that may have more or less records using the same script. But that's a future problem.

Comment: "*My final goal is to be able to extract all the data needed*' Please edit your post and add  the expected result with "all the data needed".

Comment: I lack to see what you want. Do you simply want to rename your fields and copy the file? Do you only search for a codeline to get your desired line? Is there any mapping available (What node should get what name)? Do you want all information that is occouring more than once in the same node?