# The element type "xsl:stylesheet" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</xsl:stylesheet>"

Tags: xslt-1.0

Getting an error as the title reads, someone else did the same question but it did not have any code or really much information.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csv-xml>
   <record line="1">
      <csv-field-1>1</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>7654321</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>1</csv-field-4>
      <csv-field-5>08/08/19</csv-field-5>
      <csv-field-6>08/08/19</csv-field-6>
   </record>
   <record line="2">
      <csv-field-1>2</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>12345678</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>3</csv-field-4>
   </record>
   <record line="3">
      <csv-field-1>2</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>22345679</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>7</csv-field-4>
   </record>
   <record line="4">
      <csv-field-1>2</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>32345680</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>6</csv-field-4>
   </record>
   <record line="5">
      <csv-field-1>2</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>42345681</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>2</csv-field-4>
   </record>
   <record line="6">
      <csv-field-1>3</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3></csv-field-3>
   </record>
</csv-xml>
```

I have ensured my attributes have quotes and that the my tag is ended properly and that I also have an ending tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <name>
            <xsl:copy-of select="csv-xml/[record line='1']/csv-field-4"/>
        </name>
    </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

```
Error: The element type "xsl:stylesheet" must be terminated by the matching end-tag"</xsl:stylesheet>"
```

Comment: Your error is here: `<xsl:copy-of select="csv-xml/[record line='1']/csv-field-4"/>`. That makes no sense, and since we can't see the input and don't know what you're trying to do, we can't say how to fix it. But certainly a predicate cannot be the first thing in a location step, and a node name cannot contain a space.

Comment: I have added my input XML, I am trying to extract specific fields. I can't do anything about the input. So my real goal is to try and get for example: csv-xml/record line "1"/csv-field-3 as an account number or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of field 4 from record 1, use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="csv-xml/record[@line='1']/csv-field-4"/>
```

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7nr

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Exactly what I was trying to do. Additional question, these files coming in can have more(or less) lines between the first and last line. If i wanted the same field from these lines how would that be done? For example selecting fields 3 and 4 between the 2nd and 2nd from last line.

Comment: It depends on the exact output you want. That's also what I asked on your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57458634/differentiate-between-similar-records#comment101396897_57458634